# FizzBuzz tag wiki -- should we even mention the game?

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, the suggested text reads

> Fizz buzz (also known as bizz buzz, or simply buzz) is a group word game for children to teach them about division. Players take turns to count incrementally, replacing any number divisible by three with the word "fizz", and any number divisible by five with the word "buzz".

Shouldn't we at least mention that it is generally used to refer to the programming "challenge" popularised by (?) [Jeff Atwood's post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) on the matter?  The game seems secondary here.

Answer (score 3):

Although my proposed text was approved, I do agree with you.  I was thinking about Jeff's post as well, but I first came across the original explanation.  If the tag wiki were rewritten, I suppose it could look like this:

> A programming challenge, popularized by Jeff Atwood, that prints the numbers from 1 to 100, where multiples of three print "Fizz," multiples of five print "Buzz," and multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz."

If this looks good, then either I or someone else could suggest the new edit.

Comment: That certainly looks much more relevant for the site; I'd vote for that one, as the current doesn't seem related unless you already know what it is.

Comment: Alright, then.  I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3):

There is tag wiki details section available. If there are details that you may want to add then you can add them there. It doesn't matter how much details are added. Have a look at Stackoverflow's tags for C or any popular tag. They are enormous.

Add anything that is relevant. The details section is for that. If you want to add a little history for that then there should be no problem.

Comment: Good point.  Would you be willing to edit it yourself?  The quote I gave here may need to be changed a bit.  It appears that Jeff Atwood wasn't the one who popularized this, but I can't tell for sure).

Comment: @Jamal You mean rephrase it?

Comment: You may, as you see fit.

Comment: My question is more about whether the definition is correct at all here; I don't think I've seen any questions about the children's game on this site, after all. :)